# Firebase database with MySQL database for android chat application

Tags: php, android, mysql, firebase-realtime-database

I created Android chat application. I used PHP, MySQL and Firebase. MySQL database recorded data display on the ListView. I need to chat among them. Problem is that I am using Firebase for chat application and I have to use login also Firebase chat application to solve that problem? As well as how to show online offline status through MySQL database

Comment: Firebase can handle offline too. So drop MySQL and only use Firebase.

Comment: But i have to use web application. web application and android application both are using MySQL database

Comment: web application can use firebase too, just drop mysql